# How open files on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: file, windows-phone-8

In my app I download several kinds of files (like audio,video,pdf,powerpoint,ect) .

So I receive those data from the webserver as byte[] objects.

So I would like to open them with a video player or a pdfreader now.

What am I supposed to do?

I tried this code but I guess it only works if ou have a file stored in your project's folder(that's not my case)...doesn't it?

```cs
              // Access the file.
              StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("FileToRead.pdf");

              // Launch the pdf file.
              await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

Comment: Do you have a pdf reader installed on the phone you are testing with? The Launcher.LaunchFileAsync will silently fail if there isn't a PDF reader registered with the system.

Comment: Finally this method is quite good to read files (like office's extensions)...With pdf the phone ask to download the Pdf App reader...so it's OK...I didn't try to read video and audio file with it....

Comment: The audio/video should open with the built in apps on every phone. Anything the system provides a built in experience for should work for every device (music, video, pictures, office docs, ect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get a file from Isolated Storage

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
```

Comment: I know how to get the file from ISolated storage ...i need to know how to read it if it's a video or audio or doc or pdf (all types)...thanks

Comment: I dont get your question. The only think you can do is to read the file and use `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync` for the system to take care about displaying. Or implement displaying each file type by yourself.

Comment: Did u mean the method  Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() can read all types and will launch the app which can read read the specified type of file ? or am i misunderstanding ?

Comment: The system can read many types of files (like the Office types) and for other types it will try to find an app in the store